# c gobjects.h passing color value through variable to setColor

Tags: c, variables, colors

I am trying to write a function which draws certain amount of blocks within a window. I would like to make the colors of the blocks random. Ideally I would like to have a variable which would be randomly modified each iteration making the next block with different color:

```
setColor(brick, myColorVariable);
```

Unfortunately, gobjects allows to declare color in a form of:

```
setColor(brick, "BLACK") //
```

Here is the function code:

```
void initBricks(GWindow window)
{
     int x = 5;
     int y = 100;
     int color = 0xff0000;



     GRect brick = newGRect(x,y,55,10);
     setFilled(brick, true);
     setColor(brick, PROBLEM HERE);
     add(window, brick);

}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library itself probably have a way to set colors from RGB values or palette indexes (see its documentation), but in order to use that specific function, which takes the color by its name, you can make your "palette" as an array of color names:

```
static const char* COLOR_NAMES[] = {
  "BLACK",
  "WHITE",
  ...
};
```

Then choose a random element from the array:

```
int colorIndex = rand() % (sizeof(COLOR_NAMES)/sizeof(COLOR_NAMES[0]));
setColor(brick, COLOR_NAMES[colorIndex]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! At first it didn't work as a "static const char*", but it did as just "char*"